# insert sort with insert/erase? (So I need to sort an vector, and instead of doing things by hand i am using insert and erase.)

Tags: c++

So I need to sort an vector, and instead of doing things by hand i am using insert and erase.

so far my code is

```
for (int x = 0; x < arr.size(); x++) {

     for (int y = x; y < arr.size(); y++)
     {

            if ( arr[y] < arr[x])
            {
                arr.insert(arr.begin()+x,arr[y]);
                arr.erase(arr.begin()+y+1);
            }     
     }
}
```

and yet when it runs I get time outs in my test cases and works for like 3 of them (test cases being 245+ integers of long numbers). I have to use vectors and have to use insertion sort as part of the design (finds minimum swaps to sort but thats cut from here), which i know has bad runtime.

What am I doing wrong here for the compiler to act like this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 1) You haven't given us a failing test case (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and 2) *"the compiler"?*

Comment: Use `std::rotate()` for insertion sort. [See example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: Also, see [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c) of insertion sort, plus other sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Every time when you call `arr.insert` or `arr.erase` you get O(n) complexity. Try to use `std::swap (arr[x], arr[y])` instead.